# how do I connect sshfs with password in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sshfs

I'm trying to connect to a server on my network that has PermitRootLogin without-password using

```
sshfs -f root@192.168.1.10:'/var/www/html/video/system/videos' /var/www/html/movies/system/media
```

mainly to use `chown`

I'm getting a

> root@192.168.1.10's password: Permission denied (publickey,password).
>   read: Connection reset by peer

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Are you authenticating with a password or with a key? Can you log in to the server as root over regular ssh?

Comment: Yes I can login root via : shh user@ip, and I'm not using a key

Comment: Can you login as `ssh root@ip`?